# Present Continuous or Future Simple for future?

Tags: difference

What is the difference between sentences

> "How are you getting home after party tomorrow?"

and

> "How will you get home after party tomorrow?".

Can we use here future simple? or not? Why? In the book  the first sentence is correct . but i can't understand why. Please, help

Comment: Incidentally: "after *the* party tomorrow". "Party" is singular and count, so it can't take the zero article, and even if it could, the context assures of a definite party being discussed

Answer (score -1):

The usual rule for future deals with how certain or planned out the event is. In a question, the choice of future tense makes an assumption about how much thinking and planning should go into the action.

Least planned/certain: *How will you get home tomorrow?* (future *will*)

A little more planned/certain: *How are you going to get home tomorrow?* (future *going to*)

More planning/certainty: *How are you getting home tomorrow?* (present progressive)

Most planned/certain: *How do you get home tomorrow?* (simple present; this is very unlikely in a question so far in advace)

If there is a small range of options, or the asker has a good guess already, use a more certain form. If the asker makes no assumptions or there are many possible answers, use a less certain form.

None are truly wrong, though.

Comment: Thank you very much!